# Bash: Out of Memory due to looping through results of find

Tags: bash, memory, find, out-of-memory

My bash script fails at the below point returning `xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744071562067968 bytes`:

```
for file in $(find "$BUFFER/tmpFilesArchives" -type f) 
do
    extract_VMs
done
```

The folder `$BUFFER/tmpFilesArchives` contains approx. 50.000 files.The machine has around 128GB of memory.

Is there a better (i.e. memory-saving) approach to loop through the results of find?

I was trying the below one but it also breaks.

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    extract_VMs
done < <(find "$BUFFER/tmpFilesArchives" -type f)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use `read ... -d ''` with `find ... -print0` -- that is, the delimiter that `find` uses between filenames has to match what `read` is using as a delimiter. See the examples in [BashFAQ #20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020).

Comment: 18000+ Petabytes, that's a lot of memory...